# Historial de cambios en tablas con PHP

Tags: php, sql

tengo un problema con un ejercicio que va de la siguiente manera: "crear una nueva tabla para almacenar todas las modificaciones que se realizan a los datos de forma histórica" la que se refiere es que necesita crear un historial de cambios sobre "ejemplo: tabla1" con los valores nuevos y los valores anteriores, pero mis dudas son: al actualizar los datos se pierde el valor antiguo por lo tanto debo enviar primero el valor antiguo y después actualizar ese renglón con el valor nuevo, pero no estaría creando un nuevo registro sino solo actualizando, ¿tendrán alguna guía o idea que pueda ayudarme?

Comment: Saludos. Acompaña tu planteamiento de lo que tienes realizados (código) así como ejemplos de que tienes, que procesos realizas e incluyes que error/comportamiento obtienes incluso puede ser que esperas y obtienes.

Answer (score 1):

En el ejemplo más básico,  podemos pensar que tu modelo trackeado es como un interruptor. Cada instancia tiene sólo un id y un `status`, el cual solamente puede ser on/off. No hay más campos.

| switch_id | estado |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | off |
| 2 | on |
| 3 | off |

> al actualizar los datos se pierde el valor antiguo por lo tanto debo enviar primero el valor antiguo y después actualizar ese renglón con el valor nuevo

La idea es justamente que, a sabiendas que el valor antiguo se perderá, diseñes un sistema que permita pensar en cada interruptor como una línea de tiempo, porque además de saber su estado actual queremos saber sus estados anteriores.

Específicamente, necesito ver en qué estado estaba (columna status_from) y a qué estado pasó (columna status_to). Es medio necio preguntarse a qué estado pasó si sólo puede tener dos estados, pero yo no tengo contexto, solamente veo esto:

| switch_id | estado | last_estado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | off | on |
| 2 | on | off |
| 2 | off | on |
| 3 | off | on |
| 3 | on | off |
| 3 | off | on |
| 3 | on | off |
| 3 | off | on |

Y entonces me doy cuenta que no hay manera de distinguir los cambios de un mismo interruptor. Se pisan entre sí. Lo bueno es que las BBDD ya tienen herramientas para definir un correlativo, y por cierto también tipos de dato ideales para líneas de tiempo.  Ya son **5** campos

| id | switch_id | estado | last_estado | changed_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | off | on | 2021-08-05 11:05 |
| 2 | 2 | on | off | 2021-08-05 11:07 |
| 3 | 2 | on | on | 2021-08-05 11:09 |
| 4 | 3 | off | on | 2021-08-05 11:11 |
| 5 | 3 | on | off | 2021-08-05 11:14 |
| 6 | 3 | off | on | 2021-08-05 11:15 |
| 7 | 3 | on | off | 2021-08-05 11:21 |
| 8 | 3 | off | on | 2021-08-05 11:23 |

Saber que un interruptor cualquiera pasó de 1 a 0 y 0 a 1  sirve de poco. Saber de cuál interruptor estamos hablando ya es un poco mejor. Saber a qué instante del tiempo corresponden estos registros es mejor todavía. Sin embargo el sistema todavía puede perfeccionarse en varias direcciones.

Dependiendo del negocio en cuestión, podría ser importante saber el usuario que hizo el cambio (siempre es práctico tener culpables). En otras industrias lo que sirve más es un snapshot del resto del sistema en ese instante del tiempo.

Lo importante es: **la tabla de dos campos que tiene los interruptores en ningún caso sirve para llevar su propio historial**. Por definición un modelo que represente cualquier otra cosa que no sea una línea de tiempo monovariada no tiene resolución para hacer su propia auditoría.